# custom settings for my SP site without using a list or having access to the farm/server?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

My company has a SP farm that is managed by a support team. I have an SP site in it that I have full access to. I don't have access to the farm.

I wanted to add a custom site settings page and not sure how. I know I can use an SP list but I was looking for something more user friendly.

Everything I have read online says I need to have deploy custom code on the server which I cannot do.

Do I have any other options then a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the property bag of your SP site to store your settings, you can use javascript in a sharepoint page to access the site property bag.

Take a look on these pages:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/05/06/how-to-add-properties-to-spweb-property-bag-using-jsom-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

https://derekgusoff.wordpress.com/2012/04/24/accessing-the-web-property-bag-with-javascript/

Comment: Humm. Interesting. Reading. Is it possible to access property bag values in an aspx file?

Comment: If you are asking about using .Net then yes, its very similar, take a look on this pages, just remember that only admins can access the property bag.
http://www.fivenumber.com/understanding-sharepoint-property-bag-settings/
http://bramnuyts.be/2012/01/10/working-with-spwebs-propertybag/
https://expectedexception.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/manage-spweb-propertybag-from-c-code-and-sharepoint-designer/
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49299/sharepoint-2010-net-client-object-model-add-item-to-web-property-bag

Comment: I assume I need to somehow insert that code into the aspx file to get it? Never done that before so just looking for where I should start.

Comment: This video is an excellent example of how you can start working with JavaScript inside a SharePoint page https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9WHroEFO7g please notice that you should not edit the aspx page directly instead you should use a Content Editor webpart to insert your javascript reference (as mentioned in the video).
Try using JavaScript first, since you require less effort to learn it and put your solution to work, also it is easier to migrate from one environment to other.

Comment: I know how to use JS within SP. What I was trying to do is add some custom properties to the property bag, then reference them in a masterpage without having to use JS cause that can be slow. I figured I could just reference the property like <SharePoint:Property name="..." /> or something. But I've done some reading and it looks like I have to use C# to do that and I can't add C# code directly to a masterpage so I guess I'm out of luck. :(